# Illustrator: which size for document to be printed at different scale

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, export, resize, print-production

What size should I create my AI document in order to deliver to the client and allow her to print either really large or small without specifying a size?

Comment: *Any* size proportional to the sizes you want to be able to print at...

Answer (score 1):

Vector only files saved as PDF's can print at any size without losing quality

Vector files that also contain images should be saved to the largest size they would be printed with the embedded images at 300 ppi

- Images(rasters) can alway print smaller and never print bigger

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit broad, but to give an example you can create an A4 document and your client can [print at any size](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/scale-or-resize-printed-pages.html) using **scaling** and/or **fitting** options found in the print dialog.

[image]

[image]